# Primefaces Poll only if browser tab is focused

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In implementing primefaces poll, I want to execute poll only if the browser tab is active/focused

Otherwise it should not poll data from backing bean as if multiple browser tabs are open, all the browser tabs will execute the poll regardless of being focused.

Comment: @Kukeltje I mean the browser tab

Comment: Break down your problem. Check if and how you can start/stop the poll e.g. via javascript (unrelated to the focus). Then search for generic solutions (not poll related) to check for/detect a focussed tab. It's always good to break down problems in to more manageable parts (easier to find (generic) answer for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, this question is a duplicate of a combination of two other questions. I'll answer it here anyway to emphasize the relevance (need!) to **always** try to break down your problem in more generic and hence manageable parts for which you can find answers. In this case the 'two' questions are:

- [Can I stop/start a poll from the client-side via e.g. javascript](https://www.google.nl/search?q=start%20stop%20poll%20primefaces%20via%20javascript)
- [Can I detect if a browser tab  focus.](https://www.google.nl/search?q=detect%20if%20a%20browser%20tab%20is%20focused)

Both are more easily solvable via search engines than the combined one.

I put the google searches behind the 'list items' above.

This results in

- [How to correctly start/stop a PrimeFaces Ajax Poll from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533689/how-to-correctly-start-stop-a-primefaces-ajax-poll-from-javascript)
- [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Which combined will give you the solution you need.